# "Стало первым подобным прецедентом". Что это значит?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, значение-слов, плеоназм

**Для правительства Германии назначение госслужащего на столь высокую должность в правительстве другой страны стало первым подобным прецедентом.**

Первый прецедент — плеоназм. Подобным — чему? Непонятно. Как здесь исправить?

Для правительства Германии назначение госслужащего на столь высокую должность в правительстве другой страны стало прецедентом.

Для правительства Германии назначение госслужащего на столь высокую должность в правительстве другой страны стало первым среди подобных случаев в других правительствах.

Comment: На сайте русского языка, пожалуйста, соблюдайте правила орфографии — начинайте предложение с заглавной буквы.

Answer (score 2):

[**прецедент**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/180482), -а, *муж. (книжн.)*.
Случай, служащий примером или оправданием для последующих случаев этого же рода.
Создать п. (дать повод для подобных случаев в будущем).
Установить п. (найти в прошлом сходный случай). Подобный поступок не имеет прецедентов в прошлом. Судебный п. (решение суда, обязательное для решения аналогичных дел в будущем; *спец.*).

[**подобный**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/166282/%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%94%D0%9E%D0%91%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%99)
2. **Такой, как этот.** *Никогда не встречал подобных упрямцев.*

Первый подобный прецедент = первый такой [особенный, исключительный, необычный] случай. Мне кажется, что не надо ничего исправлять, думаю, здесь нет плеоназма.

*В этом смысле арест действующего главы региональной полиции год назад был первым прецедентом, арест действующего губернатора — вторым* (Ежедневная деловая газета).

Comment: К Вам такие вопросики. (1) В чем различие сочетаний: первый подобный случай и первый подобный прецедент? Случай и прецедент здесь синонимы? (2) И если случай первый, то как он может быть подобным чему-либо?

Comment: У Ожегова: подобный = такой, как ЭТОТ. У Ушакова (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/946814): 2. ((Такой, этот (о котором говорится).** «Где еще мыслимы подобные вещи?» Маяковский. Перечислить подобного рода факты. Поступить подобным же образом. Поэтому получается: первый подобный прецедент = первый такой особенный, эксклюзивный, исключительный случай.

Comment: Прилагательное "подобный" всё-таки требует ПОДОБИЯ, хотя бы какого-нибудь. К примеру, описывается случай и говорится: где еще мыслимы подобные вещи. Все равно здесь два случая   (реальный и возможный). А в заданном примере случай ОДИН, поэтому НЕТ ТАМ ПОДОБИЯ.

Answer (score 2):

Ключевой момент в определении *прецедента*: это **предшествовавший случай**. Поэтому если речь идёт о единственном таком случае, то использование понятия прецедента **неверно**:

1) случай не "*стал прецедентом*", а только "**может стать**" таковым, если за ним последуют другие подобные;

2) Само по себе сочетание "**первый прецедент**" возможно, но уместно оно только в случае, когда как минимум "*второй* прецедент" уже состоялся, а за ним последовало то, "чему были" сопоставлены два имевшихся *прецедента*. Соответственно, третий случай может быть уже состоявшимся или предполагаться как вероятный в будущем, быть назван или подразумеваться. В исходной же фразе такого не наблюдается, и случай выглядит "**прецедентом самому себе**".

Самое простое исправление окончания предложения:

> ... стало первым подобным **случаем.**

Другие возможные варианты:

> **... может стать прецедентом (для других подобных случаев).**
>
> **... стало (первым) прецедентом для сенсационного назначения такого-то туда-то, состоявшегося три года спустя.** ("первым" - только если был и второй)

Answer (score 1):

**Немецкий эксперт назначен замминистра инноваций.**

Гражданин ФРГ Карстен Хайнц назначен заместителем министра инновационного развития Узбекистана.По итогам отбора на должность замминистра был рекомендован опытный специалист, работающий непосредственно в самом министерстве.

Для правительства ФРГ назначение госслужащего на столь высокую должность в правительстве другой страны стало первым подобным прецедентом. https://www.gazeta.uz/ru/2018/07/11/de/

**Вариант редактирования:** Для правительства ФРГ назначение госслужащего на столь высокую должность в правительстве другой страны **стало политическим прецедентом (то есть первым ТАКИМ случаем).**

**ПРЕЦЕДЕНТ**, м. [от лат. praecedens (praecedentis) - предшествующий] Случай в прошлом, служащий примером или оправданием для последующих случаев подобного рода. Не иметь прецедентов в прошлом. Установить п. (найти в прошлом сходный случай). Судебный п. (юрид.; решение суда, служащее образцом при решении аналогичных дел).

Встречаются выражения ***опасный прецедент, исторический прецедент.***

Тем не менее так говорят, например: Перенос старта биатлонной гонки с масс-стартом на 15 км у мужчин на Играх в Сочи из-за тумана **не стал первым подобным прецедентом в истории Олимпиад.**

Мне такие выражения кажутся **некорректными.**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

А ***подобный*** тут к чему?

ПОДОБНЫЙ 1. кому-чему. Сходный с кем-, чем-л., похожий на кого-, что-л. Любовь подобна безумию. 2. Такой, как тот (о котором шла речь). Подобных слов язык не допускает.

Если случай первый, **то как он может быть подобным?** Он может быть ***таким***, какой есть, но только не подобным. Это другие такие же случая **будут подобными ему.**